# Using stat for time or date -r?

Tags: time, stat

I have listed properties of a folder this way

```
stat -c $'--------------
File:              %n
Size:              %s
Owner:             %U
Group:             %G
Permissions:       %A'
```

but I am having trouble with getting the time, if I use stat for time I get a bunch of numbers at the end that I'm not to fond of, and if I use date -r instead I cant write anything on the same line before that like I have with the others.

I would like it to look like this: Modification time: 2019-11-13 11:34:54 (without +0000 at the end)

Comment: I can't see what you tried. The code seems to be for something else (not about time).

Comment: Note that if you don't include the timezone offset (`+0000`), the time becomes ambiguous. First because we don't know for sure what timezone the time is expressed in, but even if we assume it's local time, in timezone that implement DST, a given 01:10:00 on one of the DST change date could refer to two different times which are one hour appart.

Answer (score 1):

<rant><sub>Your `stat` seems to be the GNU implementation of `stat`. A `stat` command appeared in GNU coreutils in 2001, with a completely different API from that of previous `stat` implementations (like the `zsh` builtin from 1997 or the even older IRIX `stat`), duplicating the functionality of GNU `find -printf` and yet again with a different API (different `%x` format specifiers), and as you found out a less useful one. I've kept being annoyed at it since. (BSD implemented their own `stat` a year later with yet another (though better) API).</sub></rant>

Here, you could use GNU `find` instead (this syntax predates GNU `stat` by at least a decade):

```
find ./* -prune -printf '--------------
File:              %f
Size:              %s
Owner:             %u
Group:             %g
Permissions:       %m
Modification time: %TF %8TT %Tz
'
```

Which gives an output like:

```
--------------
File:              file
Size:              10
Owner:             stephane
Group:             stephane
Permissions:       -rw-r--r--
Modification time: 2019-11-13 11:34:54 +0000
```

Here using `%F %T %z` `strftime()` formatting for the time, which is a standard and unambiguous representation of the timestamp with precision up to the second, you can adapt to your need. `%T<x>` (where `<x>` is the `strftime()` format specifier) is for the last modification time; use `%A<x>` for last access time, `%C<x>` for change status time.

Remove the `%z` timezone offset specification (`%Tz` above) if you don't care for it, though that would make the time representation ambiguous.

With the `stat` builtin of `zsh` (which again predates GNU's by a few years):

```
zmodload zsh/stat
for f (*) {
  stat -F '%F %T %z' -sLH s -- $f &&
    print -r -- "--------------
File:              $f
Size:              $s[size]
Owner:             $s[uid]
Group:             $s[gid]
Permissions:       $s[mode]
Modification time: $s[mtime]"
}
```

(again, remove `%z` if you don't want to see the timezone offset).

A note of warning: for symbolic links, GNU `stat` (without `-L`), GNU `find -printf` (without `-L`), zsh `stat -L` report the modification time of the symlinks itself while GNU `date -r` (and GNU `stat -L`, and GNU `find -L -printf` and zsh `stat` without `-L`) report the mtime of the file the symlink eventually resolves to.

Comment: This might be a dumb question but it seems like thats the same output that I got with stat with the +0000 at the end

Comment: @Fredrik, see edit, you can adapt the exact format to your actual need.

Comment: Okay so I got everything working, but I still don't really understand the time, no matter how I change it it looks really weird.